# Can I safely save on heat and food?

Tags: papers-please

Too save on living costs I have been alternating the first couple of days of the game between not paying for food and not paying for heating.

My family members are cold one day and hungry the next, Are there any long term, more serious consequences for following this strategy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

There are a few additional effects of it every now and then (such as the sick son), but in general, alternating between the two is a good strategy in saving money.

Comment: Especially since the penalty for sickness ($5) is cheaper than both rent and food for a day.

Comment: @Bonnici You can't save on rent; did you mean heating?